# Android - Force VideoView to Intent.action_view [embeded videos via external player]

Tags: android, class, video, android-videoview

I have a few app to watch live streams and video clips.

The applications use embeded android video player.

After a search, i recongnized that these apps using VideoView class.

But i want to choice an external player to watch videos which triggered from this apps. (like MX Player or GP Player.)

I think i have to override the videoview class in android. Is this possible?

Or are there any other way to implement this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to modify the behavior of *your* app or *other developer's apps*?

Comment: The developer's app. Imagine i'm only an android phone user and an app has a embeded video player itself. (VideoView) I want to open that video in an external video player. So i can't access the developer's source code. May be i can override the Android source files. Is this possible? I want to force Android, for asking user to select an external video player instead of embeded video player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> May be i can override the Android source files. Is this possible?

No.

Moreover, it would not necessarily work, as there is no requirement that the video be available for viewing in a third-party app. Just because an app can play a video itself does not mean that the same video is accessible by other apps.

Comment: I know it is not neccessary for a standart user. But i need it. I want to open video with an external player to watch it in floating window. (pop-up window as like in gp player) Also, when minimizing the app's window, it stops the video, if i use an external player, i'll prevent this pause problem. Thanks for your reply, but i think, there should be a way to implement this. You know, we can edit the android source, edit videoview class and force it to intent actionview. I asked this question to learn the android guru's ideas about this.

Comment: @Yusuf: "You know, we can edit the android source, edit videoview class and force it to intent actionview" -- you are certainly welcome to build your own ROM mod that does this. But, again, that may not help, because your third-party app may not be able to access the video.